# Querying into a VIEW in SQL

Tags: sql, view

I wrote this VIEW:

```
CREATE VIEW productSalesYear AS
SELECT p.productName AS "Product Name", YEAR(o.orderDate) AS "Year",  SUM(od.quantityOrdered * od.priceEach) AS "Sales Total"
FROM products p
JOIN orderdetails od ON p.productCode = od.productCode
JOIN orders o ON od.orderNumber = o.orderNumber
GROUP BY p.productName, YEAR(o.orderDate);
```

And now I need to query the productSalesYear view to show the sales per year for the "2001 Ferrari Enzo" in 2004.

```
SELECT *
FROM productSalesYear
WHERE p.productName = '2001 Ferrari Enzo' AND YEAR(o.orderDate) = 2004;
```

However, this query doesn't work and I'm not able to get any results back. What am I doing wrong and how do I query into a VIEW?

```
SELECT *
FROM productSalesYear
WHERE "Product Name" = '2001 Ferrari Enzo' AND "Year" = 2004;
```

Would this above be correct even though it returns an empty set?

Comment: You've aliased the `p.productName` column as `Product Name` and `YEAR(o.orderDate)` as `Year`, You'll need to use these columns when querying the view.
Please don't spam tags, MySQL <> SQL-Server.

Comment: You're 1st attempt to query the view is wrong for several reasons (wrong column names in where clause and you have them aliased). The 2nd attempt looks valid to me, but since you have a space, not sure on proper format. When troubleshooting, run a `select *` from the view to get some sample data. Then write a query to match that sample data.

Comment: Often KISS is relevant - why rename the column in the view? If you're (obviously) expecting it to be `productName` then... don't give it a different alias? And if you must use a different alias, don't include characters that require you delimit it everywhere it's referenced.

Answer (score 1):

When you query a view, you can only reference the columns returned by the view, by the aliases defined for those columns in the view.

You can't reference columns by their original names in the table(s) queried by the view. You can't reference the individual table names or table aliases (e.g. `p.*` or `o.*`).

In your example, you can query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM productSalesYear
WHERE `Product Name` = '2001 Ferrari Enzo' AND `Year` = 2004;
```

Assuming you're using MySQL, you must use the back-ticks because one of these columns contains a space, and the other might be a reserved keyword (I'm not certain of that, but it doesn't hurt to be safe).

This looks very similar to your second attempt, so why didn't it work?

Because of a weird case of MySQL syntax. You can define column aliases in back-ticks or in single-quotes or double-quotes (you did the latter).

But MySQL treats double-quoted words as string literals in all other cases, unless you set the sql-mode `ANSI` or `ANSI_QUOTES`.

Comparing the string literal `'Product Name'` to a different string literal `'2001 Ferrari Enzo'`, they are obviously not equal. Likewise for your other term.

So you must use back-ticks to be certain to compare the value of the named column, not a string literal.